# Can OpenAI enforce their T&Cs requiring attribution for ChatGPT generated content?

Tags: united-states

OpenAI has the following clause in [their T&Cs](https://openai.com/api/policies/sharing-publication/):

> Creators who wish to publish their first-party written content (e.g.,
> a book, compendium of short stories) created in part with the OpenAI
> API are permitted to do so under the following conditions:
>
> - The published content is attributed to your name or company.
> - The role of AI in formulating the content is clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss, and that a typical reader
>   would find sufficiently easy to understand.
> - Topics of the content do not violate OpenAI’s Content Policy or Terms of Use, e.g., are not related to political campaigns, adult
>   content, spam, hateful content, content that incites violence, or
>   other uses that may cause social harm.
> - We kindly ask that you refrain from sharing outputs that may offend others.

Would OpenAI have any legal recourse against someone who violates these T&Cs? As per my understanding, machine-generated texts [are not copyrightable](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/us-copyright-office-rules-ai-art-cant-be-copyrighted-180979808/), so OpenAI won't be able to sue you for a copyright violation. They obviously could shutdown your account but would they have any means to enforce their attribution rules via the legal system?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

The terms of service are a contract. The primary remedy for a breach of contract are a suit for damages. If your breach damages OpenAI in a quantifiable way (including reputational damage), you can be sued.